# How to deliver different charactersets over sms?

Tags: java, encoding, sms

We have an aggregator application written in java which delivers xml based contents from third parties to different SMSC's which in turn deliver it to handsets.The xml content is mostly in plain english other than payload which could be GSM 03.38, IA5, ISO-8859-1, Unicode, binary etc.We have only one handset for testing.We find other than iso-8859-1 nothing gets delivered in its entrety i.e either some characters are missing or gibberish.Any idea how to overcome this? 
Regards,
Subhendu

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my query.
1) The xml I receive does not indicate character set.Encoding is UTF-8.I will give instance of a particular SMSC for which the protocol is http.Here we send xml messages.Outgoing xml message encoding is ISO-8859-1.For this particular SMSC, my doubt is we can only deliver latin1 messages.As it is xml message the encoding could have been utf-8.But the operator spec says that it should be iso-8859-1.So the SMSC does not want to understand anything other than latin1
2)For another smsc the protocol is TCP based.It says the payload should be IA5.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this will depend on may things, including how you're delivering the messages to the SMSCs. Are you using SMPP or some HTTP API? The documentation for the SMSC should include how to deliver the awkward characters for SMS 7bit and 16bit unicode to them. Unless you know what you're delivering to, 8bit binary is not going to be of any use.

- Does the XML you receive indicate the character set and encoding of the payload?
- Are you transforming the payload prior to delivering this to the SMSC?
- Is the [transformed] payload delivered to the SMSC conformant with their expectations?
- Does this occur with 7bit messages only, or unicode only, or everything?
- Have you tried sending a unicode and/or extended GSM character SMS to the handset to ensure it is capable of displaying everything you expect it to?
- Confirm that your bytestream is a correct representation of GSM 03.38 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38

Update your question with a few more details and possibly we can find a solution.